# Delete old records from WFFM 2.4 configured with Sitecore 7.2

Tags: wffm, sql-database

We are using WFFM 2.4 with Sitecore 7.2 and have "save to database" action in many forms.As WFFM database size is more then 21 GB now, I am looking a script to remove old records. Please share if same kind of work you have done before.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this really applies to Sitecore.  If you are interested in removing old data, just find where it's saving and Delete From the table for all records older than x date.

Comment: I agree with @DylanYoung. This is DB Admin sort of work not related to Sitecore

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is better backup WFFM db and attach the new one clear database rather than do any manipulations with old data. But in case if you wish to do it, here is script:

```
DELETE FROM Field
WHERE FormId in (select Id from Form where Timestamp < '2018/06/15')    

GO

DELETE FROM Form
WHERE Id in (select Id from Form where Timestamp < '2018/06/15')
```

Put date that you require instead of '2018/06/15' and don't forget to backup before running it.